# Error al parsear la respuesta JSON: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, ajax, php8

Al registrar al usuario me da ese error por consola pero al usuario lo sube a la base de datos. He probado todo lo que se, en el servidor el JSON es valido el formato y por el cliente tambien.Tambien he probado todos los navegadores y en servidor de pago y en todos el mismo error.

¿Alguien puede decirme como solucionarlo?.

Utilizo el patron MVC, el php me recoge por POST los dato que introduce el usuario en el formulario y los envia al modelo que se encarga de subirlo a la base de datos.

**`controlador.php`**:

```
public function setRegistro(){
        
        if($_POST){           
            if(empty($_POST['nombre']) || empty($_POST['apellidos']) || empty($_POST['usuario']) ||  empty($_POST['correo'])               
            || empty($_POST['listRolid']) || empty($_POST['listStatus']))            
            {                
                $arrResponse = array("status" => false, "msg" => 'Datos incorrectos.');
            }else{               
                $intIdPersona = intval($_POST['idpersona']);                
                $strNombre = strClean($_POST['nombre']);
                $strApellido =  strClean($_POST['apellidos']);
                $strUsuario =  strClean($_POST['usuario']);                
                $strCorreo = strClean($_POST['correo']);                
                $intListRolid = trim($_POST['listRolid']); 
                $intListStatus= intval($_POST['listStatus']);                      

                if (isset($_FILES['foto'])) {                    
                    $foto           = $_FILES['foto'];                  
                    $nombre_foto    = $foto['name'];
                    $type_foto      = $foto['type'];
                    $url_temp_foto  = $foto['tmp_name'];                    
                }else{
                    $arrResponse = array("status" => false, "msg" => 'No se encontró la foto.');
                }
                $request_registrar = "";
                if($nombre_foto != ''){
                    $strFoto = $nombre_foto ;
                }

                if($intIdPersona == 0)
                {                    
                  //Crear          
                        $strPassword =  empty($_POST['password']) ? hash("SHA256",passGenerator()) : hash("SHA256",$_POST['password']);            
                        
                        $option = 1;
                        
                        $request_registrar = $this->model->insertRegistro($strNombre,$strApellido,$strUsuario,
                        $strCorreo,$strPassword,$strFoto,$intListRolid,$intListStatus);             
                }else{
                    //Actualizar
                                       
                        if($nombre_foto == ''){
                            if($_POST['foto_actual'] != 'usuarioblanco.png' && $_POST['foto_remove'] == 0 ){
                                $strFoto = $_POST['foto_actual'];
                            }
                        }
                        $option = 2;
                        
                        $strPassword =  empty($_POST['password']) ? "" : hash("SHA256",$_POST['password']);
                    
                        
                        $request_registrar = $this->model->updateRegistro($intIdPersona,$strNombre,$strApellido,$strUsuario,
                        $strCorreo,$strPassword,$strFoto,$intListRolid,$intListStatus);                        
                    
                }
                if($request_registrar > 0 )
                {                    
                    if($option == 1)
                    {
                        $arrResponse = array('status' => true, 'msg' => 'Datos guardados correctamente.');
                        if($nombre_foto != ''){ uploadImage($foto,$strFoto); }
                    }else{
                        $arrResponse = array('status' => true, 'msg' => 'Datos Actualizados correctamente.');
                        if($nombre_foto != ''){ uploadImage($foto,$strFoto); }

                        if(($nombre_foto == '' && $_POST['foto_remove'] == 1 && $_POST['foto_actual'] != 'usuarioblanco.png')
                            || ($nombre_foto != '' && $_POST['foto_actual'] != 'usuarioblanco.png')){
                            deleteFile($_POST['foto_actual']);
                        }
                    }
                }else if($request_registrar == 'exist'){
                    $arrResponse = array('status' => false, 'msg' => '¡Atención! El Registro ya existe.');
                }else{
                    $arrResponse = array("status" => false, "msg" => 'No es posible almacenar los datos.');
                }
            }            
            
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($arrResponse,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);            
        }
        die();    
    }
```

javascript:

```
if (document.getElementById("formRegistro")) {

        let formRegistro = document.querySelector("#formRegistro");

        formRegistro.onsubmit = function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            let strNombre = document.querySelector('#nombre').value;
            let strApellido = document.querySelector('#apellidos').value;
            let strUsuario = document.querySelector('#usuario').value;
            let strCorreo = document.querySelector('#correo').value;
            let strPassword = document.querySelector('#password').value;
            let intListRolid = document.querySelector('#listRolid').value.trim();
            let intStatus = document.querySelector('#listStatus').value;


            if (strNombre == '' && strApellido == '' && strUsuario == '' && strCorreo == '' && strPassword == ''
                && intListRolid == '' && intStatus == '') {

                swal("Atención", "Todos los campos son obligatorios.", "error");
                return false;
            }

            let request = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
            let ajaxUrl = base_url + '/registrar/setRegistro';
            let formData = new FormData(formRegistro);
            
            request.open("POST", ajaxUrl, true);
            request.send(formData);
            console.log(formData);
            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                
                if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                    let responseText = request.responseText.trim();
                    console.log("Respuesta del servidor:", responseText);
                    try {
                        
                        let objData = JSON.parse(responseText);
                        console.log(objData);
                
                        if (objData.status) {
                            // Código para manejar la respuesta cuando los datos se guardan correctamente
                            // ...
                        } else {
                            if (objData.msg && objData.msg === 'No se encontró la foto.') {
                                // Manejar el caso cuando no se encuentra la foto
                                Swal.fire({
                                    icon: 'error',
                                    title: 'Error',
                                    text: 'No se encontró la foto.',
                                    showConfirmButton: false,
                                    timer: 2500
                                });
                            } else {
                                // Mostrar mensaje de error genérico
                                Swal.fire({
                                    icon: 'error',
                                    title: 'Datos no guardados',
                                    showConfirmButton: false,
                                    timer: 2500
                                });
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (error) {
                        console.error('Error al parsear la respuesta JSON:', error);
                    }
                }
                return false;            
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Un clásico... ¿Es realmente un JSON lo que estás recibiendo?

Comment: Ve por consola o por el navegador si estás recibiendo un json

Comment: apostaría a que el primer carácter que recibes es un chevron `<`